# UITextview height in UITableview swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uitextview

Im facing a problem while setting up `UITextview` in `UITableViewCell`. As the function **heightforrowatindexpath** is running before **cellforrowatindexpath** so I cannot calculate the size of content of `UITextview`.

Im calculating the size by simply `textview.contentSize.height` in `cellforrowatindexpath` function.

Im basically want `UITextview` contentHeight fit in `UITableViewCell` so no scroll is visible for every `UITextView` and it will show full content by increasing the height of `UITableViewCell`.

I also a `UILabel` just above the `UITextView` in `UITableViewCell` and I tried to set contraints for both but unable to achieve my goal.

How can I calculate the size of `UITableViewCell` dynamically in following function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

}
```

P.S: Is it possible to use increase the `UITableViewCell` height a little bit according to device height, using auto layout or some technique else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just pass your textView with the content in order to calculate the height of the textView

```
func calculateHeight(textView:UITextView, data:String) -> CGRect {

    var newFrame:CGRect! 

    // I was using the HTML content here. If your content is not HTML you can just pass the stringValue to your textView
    do {
        let attr = try NSAttributedString(data: html.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF16StringEncoding)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
        textView.attributedText = attr

    }catch {
        //Handle Exceptions
    }

    let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
    textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
    newFrame = textView.frame
    newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
    print("height \(newFrame.height)")
    return newFrame
}
```

You can call this method in your `heightForRowAtIndex` so that in return you can get a new updated frame from which you can fetch the new updated height.

Make sure to keep `scrollEnabled` as `false` of your cell's textView in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        //Cell making here......

        cell.yourTextView.scrollEnabled = false
        return cell  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) In heightForRowAtIndexPath give the cell size the following:

return UITableViewAutomaticDimension

2) ... and add the following:

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

I hope it helps ...